# Forced to identify photos during login on Facebook

Tags: facebook, login

Every time I log in to my account I have to go through a security check asking me to identify photos of my friends that are tagged, which is impossible.

Now what should I do? I have already tried several times.

Comment: which browser you use

Answer (score -2):

the simplest n easy way to pass through this security check is:

1. You will need two browsers or two devices with high internet speed.
2. You will need a friend of u which is in your account.
3. Now open your n your friend's id.
4. Your id will go on to the security check point but your friend will be logged in.
5. Now see which pics n names appear in ur security chechk n quickly open ur profile through ur frnd account n search the name in your frndz n select the photos of him n see if the image is present there if not then quickly serach for the other name and his photos.
6. Like this trick u can pass theis security check.!

Comment: Please use standard English, not txtspk.